# How to use websocket-sharp in an Azure Blazor web app

Tags: azure, websocket, blazor

I'm totally stuck on this one, run out of things to try.

Visual Studio 2022. Used project templates to create a demo Blazor app. Runs fine, locally and when published to Azure.

Am using http://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/ to add WebSocket server and client.

I have it all working fine locally.

In one of my razor service .cs files I have:

```
m_WSServer = new WebSocketServer(3333, false);
m_WSServer.AddWebSocketService<Laputa>("/" + "Laputa");
```

and in one of my client-side .razor files I have:

```
m_WSClient = new WebSocket("ws://11.22.33.44:3333/Laputa");
```

As I say, it all works fine locally.

Obviously it won't run as-is when published to Azure. I make these two changes before publishing:

In service I now have:

```
m_WSServer = new WebSocketServer(3333, true);
m_WSServer.AddWebSocketService<Laputa>("/" + "Laputa");
```

(true argument to use ssl as Azure must use ssl)

and in client .razor file I have:

```
m_WSClient = new WebSocket("wss://mywebappname.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa");
```

So used wss instead of ws.

Form what I can see, websocket server is running, but when I call connect method on websocket client it soon receives an onClose event from the websocket server.

Can anyone see me error? Only thing I can think of is that my URL for websocket client connection might be wrong? i.e. "wss://mywebappname.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa" but I've tried many variations.

(I should add that I have enabled websockets on my Azure app).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your application GIT repository?

Comment: Yes, thanks for having a look I've just used the default Blazor demo app. On the left-hand menu you'll see the option "Web Sockets Tester". The functionality of the three buttons are obvious. https://github.com/gnitsuk/BlazorWebSocketsTester

Comment: can you tell me how you configured this "wss://mywebappname.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa". In our web application we have only "mywebappname.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa" in real time application. If you want to configure webhooks in web application, we can use azure web [pubsub](https://i.imgur.com/aDxeoKp.png) or with SignalR

Comment: I didn't configure "wss://mywebappname.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa" in any way. Previously when I've used node.js (rather than C#) I had to use secure sockets and wss:// worked. If I leave off the wss:// then I'll get the error: An invalid URI string: mywebsitename.azurewebsites.net:3333/Laputa (Parameter 'url')'. If you are able to test, the does the app work for you locally but not on Azure?

Comment: I am able to run the application locally with your code.

Comment: ok, that's good to know, thanks. As far as you know, should this code be able to work when published to Azure? (I mean, with the alterations I have applied - using true for secure websockets and wss instead of ws). The websockets-sharp website does talk of the need to set ServerCertificate for server etc. But I never had to do this with my nodeJS web servers (also on Azure).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same sample code which you shared, and I am able to run it locally.

[image]

- No port number (e.g., `:3333`) should be included in the URL when you are using the standard WebSocket secure (wss) port (port 443) for your Azure-hosted application.

```
m_WSClient = new WebSocket("wss://mywebappname.azurewebsites.net/Laputa");
```

Here Iam using a custom domain, so I imported certificate. By setting the second parameter to `true` when creating the `WebSocketServer`, you are enabling SSL, it allows you to use the `wss://` protocol for secure WebSocket communication. This is the correct approach for secure WebSocket connections.

[image]

- Enabled web sockets option "on" in webapp.

[image]

Configure your webapplication with premium plan because of custom pages.

[image]